# How to bring the current context when a module is being executed into a module?

Tags: elixir

I have this:

```
defmodule MyTest1 do
  def print_data do
    IO.puts("***this module: #{__MODULE__}")
  end
end
```

If I call it from within other module, it’ll still print the name of the original module where it's defined --> Elixir.MyTest1.

How to change it such that it’ll print the name of a module it’s being called from? Without having to pass `__MODULE__` as an argument to the function `print_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired behavior is obviously impossible. [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is a compiled language, and [`__MODULE__`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#__MODULE__/0) lifetime is a compilation phase only. The code above is compiled into BEAM *before* any call to it could ever be resolved. During the compilation, it would put the real name instead of [`__MODULE__`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#__MODULE__/0) placeholder and in the BEAM there would be zero references to the aforementioned placeholder.

Getting the caller context is somewhat possible with macros ([`__CALLER__`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#__CALLER__/0),) but still it’d be a compile-time resolution. Macros produce the AST that is injected during the compilation stage, so there is absolutely no chance to resolve caller during the arbitrary call to another module in runtime.

Comment: why do you say  `but still not in the sense you expect.` ? I've just done that via a macros at my computer and it works well.

Comment: Great, that probably means I misinterpret your expectations. I will update the answer.

Comment: Also, I strongly encourage you to now mess with macros until you get a clear understanding of compilation vs. runtime difference. It’d bring more issues than profit.

Comment: Aleksei - how much strongly?

Comment: Ouch, sorry, there was a typo; I meant “not to use,” not “now to use.” Anyway, macros might seem to be a great tool to tweak stuff around, but there is a rule of thumb: if something can be done without macro, do it without macro. Macros do inject alien AST directly in the caller code and that might drastically change the behavior without any evident cause, what leads to code that is extremely hard to debug and even reason about. Refactoring the code that is using macros might also become a nightmare. And, the last, but not the least, macros could be avoided in 95% of cases even if seem needed.

Comment: Ok. Can I avoid macros in my case? And let the code remain flexible and with no redundant repetition

Comment: Yes, in [tag:elixir] we pass a module name as a parameter in such a case. Injecting the AST into several modules would blow up the size of the BEAMs for no reason. Imagine you are to call this `print_data/0` from 1000 modules—in a case of macro that would lead to 1000 copies of the nearly same AST injected into 1000 different places.

Comment: 1) I have 10-20 modules where   the macros  code would be injected into. This isn't many. 2) How big that AST for `print_data/0`? 3) How is that different from calling that function from each module -- without macros? I'd still have to insert the function manually into each module. This wouldn't increase its size?

Comment: There are many ways to determine that yourself. In any case, AST won’t survive compilation, so you are actually interested in how big is the compiled result in the resulting BEAM. Want to use macros—use them. I warned you about possible caveats.